# How to add column dynamically in datatable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create datatable in which i want to add column names dynamically, my column names are coming from database, which is not fixed column name every time different its depend on user selection
i using sql server and c#.

Comment: What have you done? Before asking a question you must face to a situation. Update the question with the code.

Comment: It's pretty simple: `table.Colums.Add("Column Name");`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you simply want to load data from a database into a DataTable, take a look at xxxDataAdapter.Fill.  For example, if you are working with SQL Server, it would be [`SQLDataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Following code add column and row dynamically in the datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var properties = typeof(model).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
}

foreach (var data in taskData)
{
   var values = new object[properties.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
   {
       values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(data, null);
   }
   dt.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also try this one.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
{
     column.Caption = "Name";
     column.ColumnName = "ColumnName";
     column.DataType = typeof(String);
     dt.Columns.Add(column);
}
```